# Angular universal SSR, first call to find user's ip went from server instead of client?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

We have made Angular universal server side rendering application so that html tags are shown in view source for SEO purposes. We have implemented localization in our app to serve data according to country. We find the ip at the start of application and then using that ip, get data for that specific country/ region.

The issue is that after SSR, application first renders from server and the ip call goes from server and finds the ip of server. But we want the ip of the client's browser. Is their any way we can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the angular app with the client IP adress

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) =>
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      {
        provide: 'clientIPAddress',
        useValue: options.req.connection.remoteAddress, //Provides the client IP address to angular
      },
    ],
  })(_, options, callback)
)
```

Then in your angular app, inject that value

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';


export class YourServiceOrComponent{
constructor(@Optional() @Inject('clientIPAddress') ipAddress: string) 
{
    if(ipAddress)
    {
        //Server side
    }
    else
    {
    //client side
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @David, I tried to apply your solution but always get null value of ipAddress, connection.remoteAddress is not attribute of options.req.

Comment: @dlam do a `console.log`  on `options.req` and see what's inside

Comment: it returns ipAddress null value, seems can't recevice variable clientIPAddress. I'm run node server.js, test localhost in chrome, did I try correctly?